# Laravel редирект на /login даже после регистрации или залогинивания

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel5, аутентификация

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: даже после регистрации, или авторизации меня всё-равно редиректит из `/home` на `/login`.
Над проблемой бьюсь долго и что только не пытался делать.
Вот мои маршруты, которые участвуют в этом процессе:

```
Auth::routes();   

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Вот код контроллера. Я его, кстати, почти не менял:

```
    public function __construct()
{        
    $this->middleware('auth');

}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    //return view('home');
    return redirect('users/{id}');
}
```

Дело в том, что понимаю, что проблема в конструкторе, но если его убрать, или сделать пустым, то ничего хорошего из этого не выходит, пользователь просто не логинится: [image: страничка на которую у меня стоит редирект отображает нормально, но как видно из скрина- аутентификации не происходит]
Если открыть `Authenticate.php` и поменять стандартный код:

```
    protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

допустим сделать редирект на `/home`, то тоже ничего не выйдет хорошего, будет бесконечный редирект на `/home`

Answer (score 0):

а вот это что:

```
return redirect('users/{id}');
```

?

Почему в роутах этого маршрута нет?

Вы бы полностью роуты выложили?

И полностью HomeController